# Clojure: map function isn't returning something I can eval

Tags: dictionary, clojure

I'm writing a little "secret santa" program to get my hands dirty with Clojure, and I'm stumbling with my output.

The program takes a list of sets (Santas), extracts their emails into another list, then randomly assigns recipients to Santas. I think I've mostly got it, but when I try to output the results of my `map`, I'm getting `#<Fn@dc32d15 clojure.core/map$fn__4549>`,

```
(ns secret-santas-helper.core
  (:require [clojure.pprint :as pprint])
  (:gen-class))

(def santas [{:name "Foo" :email "foo@gmail.com"}
             {:name "Bar" :email "bar@gmail.com"}
             {:name "Baz" :email "baz@gmail.com"}])

(defn pluck
  "Pull out the value of a given key from a seq"
  [arr k]
  (map #(get % k) arr))

(defn find-first
  "Find the first matching value"
  [f coll]
  (first (filter f coll)))

(defn assign-santas
  "Iterate over a list of santas and assign a recipient"
  [recipients santas]
  (let [r (atom recipients)])
  (map (fn [santa]
          (let [recipient (find-first #(= % (get santa :email)) @recipients)]
            (assoc santa :recipient recipient)
            (swap! recipients (remove #(= % recipient) recipients))))))

(defn -main []
  (let [recipients (shuffle (pluck santas :email))
        pairs (assign-santas recipients santas)]
      (pprint/pprint pairs)))
```

Comment: Something seems wrong. In `assign-santas`, the `santas` argument is not used, the first `let` binding is a no-op since it is closed on the same line, and `map` doesn't actually map over a collection. I recommend stripping this code down further, that way you'll probably find the answer by yourself quickest.

Comment: yeah that is absolutely a problem - I wasn't supplying `santas` to the map.  Not _the_ problem, but certainly *a* problem :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Also be careful on how you use `map`. You are returning the result of your `swap!` which I don't believe is what you are aiming at.

Keep working on getting your version compiling and functioning correctly. I wanted to give an alternative solution to your problem that works less with mutation and instead is focused on combining collections.

```lisp
(def rand-santas
  "Randomize the current santa list"
  (shuffle santas))

(def paired-santas
  "Use partition with overlap to pair up all random santas"
  (partition 2 1 rand-santas))

(def final-pairs
  "Add the first in the list as santa to the last to ensure everyone is paired"
  (conj paired-santas (list (last rand-santas) (first rand-santas))))

(defn inject-santas 
  "Loop through all pairs and assoc the second pair into first as the secret santa"
  [pairs]
  (map 
    (fn [[recipent santa]]
      (assoc recipent :santa santa))
    pairs))

(defn -main [] 
  (pprint/pprint (inject-santas final-pairs)))
```

Comment: That solution worked well - now I just need to dig into it and understand it :)

Comment: You could do `(partition 2 1 (take 1 rand-santas) rand-santas)`, to get the ending items paired as well.

Comment: Note that this algorithm will never give mulitple "cycles". For example, if there are 6 santas a, b, c, d, e, and f, then the solution will never propose a-b-c-a; d-e-f-d.

Answer (score 4):

Your `assign-santas` function is returning a map transducer. When you apply `map` to a single argument, it returns a transducer that will perform that transform in a transducing context. Most likely you intended to provide a third arg, `santas`, to map over.

Inside the `assign-santas` function, you are using `@` to deref a value that is not an atom. Perhaps you meant `@r` instead of `@recipients`, but your let block is stops too soon and doesn't yet provide the `r` binding to the rest of the function body.

Answer (score 3):

Lisp (in general) and Clojure (specific case) are different, and require a different way of approaching a problem. Part of learning how to use Clojure to solve problems seems to be *unlearning* a lot of habits we've acquired when doing imperative programming. In particular, when doing something in an imperative language we often think "How can I start with an empty collection and then add elements to it as I iterate through my data so I end up with the results I want?". This is not good thinking, Clojure-wise. In Clojure the thought process needs to be more along the lines of, "I have one or more collections which contain my data. How can I apply functions to those collections, very likely creating intermediate (and perhaps throw-away) collections along the way, to finally get the collection of results I want?".

OK, let's cut to the chase, and then we'll go back and see why we did what we did. Here's how I modified the original code:

```
(def santas [{:name "Foo" :email "foo@gmail.com"}
             {:name "Bar" :email "bar@gmail.com"}
             {:name "Baz" :email "baz@gmail.com"}])

(def kids [{:name "Tommy" :email "tommy@gmail.com"}
           {:name "Jimmy" :email "jimmy@gmail.com"}
           {:name "Jerry" :email "jerry@gmail.com"}
           {:name "Johny" :email "johny@gmail.com"}
           {:name "Juney" :email "juney@gmail.com"}])

(defn pluck
  "Pull out the value of a given key from a seq"
  [arr k]
  (map #(get % k) arr))

(defn assign-santas [recipients santas]
  ; Assign kids to santas randomly
  ; recipients is a shuffled/randomized vector of kids
  ; santas is a vector of santas

  (let [santa-reps  (inc (int (/ (count recipients) (count santas))))  ; counts how many repetitions of the santas collection we need to cover the kids
        many-santas (flatten (repeat santa-reps santas))]              ; repeats the santas collection 'santa-reps' times
    (map #(hash-map :santa %1 :kid %2) many-santas recipients)
  )
)

(defn assign-santas-main []
  (let [recipients (shuffle (pluck kids :email))
        pairs (assign-santas recipients (map #(%1 :name) santas))]
      ; (pprint/pprint pairs)
      pairs))
```

I created a separate collection of kids who are supposed to be assigned randomly to a santa. I also changed it so it creates an `assign-santas-main` function instead of `-main`, just for testing purposes.

The only function changed is `assign-santas`. Instead of starting with an empty collection and then trying to mutate that collection to accumulate the associations we need I did the following:

1. Determine how many repetitions of the `santas` collection are needed so we have have at least as many santas as kids (wait - we'll get to it... :-). This is just

   `TRUNC(#_of_kids / #_of_santas) + 1`

or, in Clojure-speak

```
`(inc (int (/ (count recipients) (count santas))))`
```

2. Create a collection which the `santas` collection repeated as many times as needed (from step 1). This is done with

   `(flatten (repeat santa-reps santas))`

This duplicates (`repeat`) the `santas` collection `santa-reps` times (`santa-reps` was computed by step 1) and then `flatten`'s it - i.e. takes the elements from all the sub-collections (try executing `(repeat 3 santas)` and see what you get) and just makes a big flat collection of all the sub-collection's elements.

3. We then do

   `(map #(hash-map :santa %1 :kid %2) many-santas recipients)`

This says "Take the first element from each of the `many-santas` and `recipients` collections, pass them in to the anonymous function given, and then accumulate the results returned by the function into a new collection". (New collection, again - we do that a lot in Clojure). Our little anonymous function says "Create an association (`hash-map` function), assigning a key of `:santa` to the first argument I'm given, and a key of `:kid` to the second argument". The `map` function then returns that collection of associations.

If you run the `assign-santas-main` function you get a result which looks like

```
({:kid "jimmy@gmail.com", :santa "Foo"}
 {:kid "tommy@gmail.com", :santa "Bar"}
 {:kid "jerry@gmail.com", :santa "Baz"}
 {:kid "johny@gmail.com", :santa "Foo"}
 {:kid "juney@gmail.com", :santa "Bar"})
```

(I put each association on a separate line - Clojure isn't so gracious when it prints it out - but you get the idea). If you run it again you get something different:

```
({:kid "juney@gmail.com", :santa "Foo"}
 {:kid "tommy@gmail.com", :santa "Bar"} 
 {:kid "jimmy@gmail.com", :santa "Baz"}
 {:kid "johny@gmail.com", :santa "Foo"}
 {:kid "jerry@gmail.com", :santa "Bar"})
```

And so on with each different run.

Note that in the rewritten version of `assign-santas` the entire function could have been written on a single line. I only used a `let` here to break the calculation of `santa-reps` and the creation of `many-santas` out so it was easy to see and explain.

For me, one of the things I find difficult with Clojure (and this is because I'm still very much climbing the learning curve - and for me, with 40+ years of imperative programming experience and habits behind me, this is a pretty steep curve) is just learning the basic functions and how to use them. Some that I find handy on a regular basis are:

```
map
apply
reduce
  I have great difficulty remembering the difference between apply and
  reduce. In practice, if one doesn't do what I want I use the other.
repeat
flatten
interleave
partition
hash-map
mapcat
```

and of course all the "usual" things like `+`, `-`, etc.

I'm pretty sure that someone who's more expert than I am at Clojure (not much of a challenge :-) could come up with a way to do this faster/better/cooler, but this might at least give you a different perspective on how to approach this.

Best of luck.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a ton for the in-depth walk-through; I really appreciate it.  Coming from JS (even functional JS), Clojure is a bit of a brain twister.

Comment: You're welcome. I think getting my brain twisted occasionally is a Good Thing - just not at the time. :-) The previous language that forced me to really *learn* a New Way of Doing Things was Smalltalk. I'd pick it up, try it out, put it down - rinse, repeat - until after several *years* of on-again, off-again messing with it I finally Got It. Note: it's syntax and approach are far different than most empirical languages. It was hard to learn. It taught me more than just about any other language. Clojure is having a similar effect. Hmmmmm.... :-)  Best of luck.

Comment: What is an empirical language? Did you mean imperative?

Comment: (*sigh*) You are, of course, correct - I meant 'imperative'. (Next time I'll probably put it down as 'imperial'. Too many words, too little time... :-)